# React access props

Tags: reactjs

I import a simple json and pass it down to a component, done like this:

```
//Json
{
  "sidebar": [
    {
      "isOpen": false
    }
  ]
}

//Passing it to sidebar-component
const {sidebar} = this.props;
 <Sidebar {...sidebar} />
```

How can I access the "isOpen"-value from inside of the sidebar-component?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're spreading an array into props, which you can't do. You can only spread objects. Please read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Comment: It's very unusual to spread arrays as props. Are you sure that's what you want do do?

Comment: @AndyRay: are you sure it's not possible? Arrays are objects after all. I haven't tested it though, hence I'm asking.

Comment: i'm guessing it will make your prop keys 0, 1, 2, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can not use spread operator as you would for an object on arrays. Instead you can map your sidebars and use spread operator for each object.

```
const data = {
  sidebar : [
    {
      "isOpen": false
    }
  ]
}


data.sidebar.map( s => <Sidebar {...s} /> )
```

Here is the error you will get when you use arrays :

> Warning: Unknown props `0`, `1` on  tag. Remove these props from
>   the element.

Comment: You are welcome. You might accept the answer as correct if it helped.